# Will final version of 12.04 use the power management changes found in kernel 3.3

Tags: kernel, power-management, 12.04

I have seen in some version of Ubuntu that instead of making a huge change to update to the latest kernel, they take some of the good stuff out of it, for the sake of stability and put it on a previous version.

In this case, kernel 3.3 has seen some very good power management enhancements that are not all found in the kernel 3.2. My question then is: Will this updates in 3.3 be somehow pulled into the 3.2 kernel used for Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are referring to the fix to the [infamous ASPM power regression](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/760131), according to [this Phoronix article](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA0MTM) the fix has already been pulled into Precise. And looking at the [changelog for the current Precise kernel](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_3.2.0-10.18/changelog), the patch "pci: Rework ASPM disable code" was pulled into Ubuntu's kernel at version 3.2.0-3.9. So yes :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is more information from the Ubuntu Kernel team on the work being done in this area:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagementRC6
- [Improving Battery Life in Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS](http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2011/12/improving-battery-life-in-ubuntu.html)
- [Improving Battery Life in Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS (part 2)](http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2012/01/improving-battery-life-in-ubuntu.html)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks
- [RC6 Call for testing in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin LTS](http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2012/02/rc6-call-for-testing-in-ubuntu-1204.html)

Comment: +1. The first link is awesome. The 2nd and 3rd are very good for information. The last one will help 12.04 a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have problems with the "original" 12.04-kernel, hit it with the 3.3 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

I still do 11.04 and the 3.3 works for me too, so i would give it a shot.